# Filemaker generated excel xml with xslt opens in excel mac 2011 but not in excel windows 2013

Tags: xml, excel, xslt, filemaker

I created an xml file with xslt transform from filemaker (on a mac).  File opens and formats as intended in Excel Mac 2011.

However when my client attempts to open the same file in Excel 2013 (on windows pc) , gets an error message that file can not be opened (they tried on 2 different laptops)

This is the log message created by Excel (Windows):

```
XML ERROR in Table
REASON: Bad Value
GROUP:  Row
TAG:    Cell
ATTRIB: StyleID
VALUE:  GroupSubtotalCenter1

XML ERROR in Table
REASON: Bad Value
GROUP:  Row
TAG:    Cell
ATTRIB: StyleID
VALUE:  GroupSubtotal1

XML ERROR in Table
REASON: Bad Value
GROUP:  Row
TAG:    Cell
ATTRIB: StyleID
VALUE:  GroupSubtotalPercent1
```

And here is a link to the file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/inn6gs5pg7fnmqk/SalesReport.xls?dl=0

Note: I have been using the same styles on other reports generated by the same filemaker db, that open just fine both on Windows and Mac.

Any ideas why this is happening and/or how to fix/debug?

Comment: It may be due to case-sensitivity. You have defined the style as `<Style ss:ID="GroupSubTotalCenter1">`, but reference it as `<Cell ss:StyleID="GroupSubtotalCenter1">`

Comment: @TimC That would have broken the file on a mac as well I think

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out ;)

Comment: I tried to change all three reported styles as suggested by @TimC . I still get the corruption error, but now it lets me open and view the files.

Comment: You might get an error message because you are using the .xls extension, which Excel expects to be a binary file, but it then finds an XML file instead. You could try changing the file to have an .xml extension, and adding the processing instruction `<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>` to the XML file, but I am not sure if this is still supported.

Comment: @TimC I see, thank you. I can live with the warning